# Query to add next row's same column

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need a query that can sum like this (previous row with current row)

```
1  1
2  3
3  5
4  7
5  9
```

I want row1.MoneyPaid + row2.MoneyPaid, row2.MoneyPaid + row3.MoneyPaid,row3.MoneyPaid + row4.MoneyPaid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  SELECT m1.moneypaid, 
   ( SELECT TOP 1 m2.moneypaid 
     FROM @Money m2 
     WHERE m2.id <m1.id  
     ORDER BY m2.id  DESC
   ) AS Prev_Value
   ,m1.moneypaid + ( SELECT TOP 1 m2.moneypaid 
     FROM @Money m2 
     WHERE m2.id <m1.id  
     ORDER BY m2.id  DESC
   )
```